# How do i run multiple python files through command prompt

Tags: python, spyder, multiple-projects

I need help with opening my first ever game in python. I followed a tutorial and in the tutorial it said that i should run the file through the command prompt. the problem is i don't know how to run files through command prompt and i also don't know how to open multiple.

Any help would me appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in command prompt, use as below.

```
python your_file.py

or

/Path/to/python.exe your_file.py
```

I hope your code is a python script that offers service, If so, you can open multiple command prompts and do it As above.

**Additional help:**

Winkey + R - opens run window

Type cmd in it.

It will open command prompt.